# Prove that linear functionals on the space of polynomial functions is a basis for $V^{*}.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is one of those examples from *Linear Algebra by Kenneth Hoffman, Ray Kunze(p. 100)*:

> Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomial functions from $R$ into $R$ which have degree less than or equal to 2. Let $t_{1}, t_{2},$ and $t_{3}$ be any three distinct real numbers, and let $$L_{i}(p) = p(t_{i}).$$ Then $L_{1}, L_{2},$ and $L_{3}$ are linear functionals on $V$. `These functionals are linearly independent;` for, suppose $$L=c_{1}L_{1}+c_{2}L_{2}+c_{3}L_{3}.$$ if $L=0$, i.e. if $L(p)=0$ for each $p$ in $V$, then applying $L$ to `the particular polynomial 'functions'` $1, x, x^{2},$ we obtain $$\begin{align} c_{1}+c_{2}+c_{3}&=0\\t_{1}c_{1}+t_{2}c_{2}+t_{3}c_{3}&=0\\t^{2}_{1}c_{1}+t^{2}_{2}c_{2}+t^{2}_{3}c_{3}&=0 \end{align}$$ From this it follows that $c_{1}=c_{2}=c_{3}=0$, because (as a short computation shows) the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\ t_{1}&t_{2}&t_{3}\\ t^{2}_{1}&t^{2}_{2}&t^{2}_{3}\end{bmatrix}$$ is invertible when $t_{1},t_{2},$ and $t_{3}$ are distinct...

**Although I agree the scalars $c_{i}$ must be $0$**, I don't see how it leads to the conclusion that the $L_{i}$ are linearly independent. In other words, **is it safe to say that $L_{i}(1), L_{i}(x), L_{i}(x^2)$ sufficiently represent $L_{i}(p)$ for every $p$**? It seems to me that the choice of polynomial functions above is somewhat related to the conclusion, but I'm not able to confidently say that's true. Any comments or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's the definition of linear independence. $L_1,\dotsc,L_k$ are linearly independent iff from a linear relation $\sum_{\kappa = 1}^k c_{\kappa} L_{\kappa} = 0$ it follows that $c_1 = \dotsc = c_k = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The author showed that $L_{i}(1), L_{i}(x), L_{i}(x^2)$ are linearly independent. **Is it equivalent to say that $L_{i}(p)$ are linearly independent?** I'm confused here.

Comment: No, the author showed that $L_1,L_2,L_3$ are linearly independent. They assumed that $L := c_1 L_1 + c_2 L_2 + c_3 L_3 = 0$. That is, $L(p) = 0$ for all $p$. Then they used that $L(p_i) = 0$ for three particular polynomials (since these three form a basis of $V$, that already implies $L(p) = 0$ for all $p\in V$, but even if we were looking at a larger space, where these three polynomials don't form a basis that would suffice to deduce linear independence) to deduce that $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer It seems that we need to be careful in selecting which particular polynomials we use to deduce that conclusion. I'm aware of the fact that $1, x, x^{2}$ is a basis for $V$, however I don't know how it affects the process of selecting polynomials. Can you give me an algebraic proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L_1, L_2, L_3$ are vectors (read: linear functionals) in the vector space $V^*$. By the definition of linear independence in a vector space, $L_1, L_2, L_3$ are independent iff
$$
\underbrace{0 = c_1 L_1 + c_2 L_2 + c_3 L_3}_{(1)} \implies \underbrace{c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0}_{(2)}.
$$
So to prove independence, we start with equation $(1)$ and must prove that this implies equation $(2)$.

Since $0, L_1, L_2, L_3$ are linear functionals, $(1)$ implies that 
$$
0(p) = c_1 L_1(p) + c_2 L_2(p) + c_3 L_3(p) \qquad \forall p \in V.
$$
In particular, the above is true for $p = 1$, $p = x$, and $p = x^2$. Writing these three equations down gives the matrix equation 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} L_1(1) & L_2(1) & L_3(1) \\ L_1(x) & L_2(x) & L_3(x) \\ L_1(x^2) & L_2(x^2) & L_3(x^2)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ t_1 & t_2 & t_3 \\ t_1^2 & t_2^2 & t_3^2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which you agree implies $c_i = 0$. Recall that $c_i = 0$ is equation $(2)$. So we have used equation $(1)$ to prove equation $(2)$, which establishes linear independence of $L_1, L_2, L_3$.

(It is worth noting that, as you say, the choice of polynomials $p$ is important; had we not chosen the $p$ (and $t_i$) wisely, the matrix equation we'd get would not imply $c_i = 0$, and we would not have proved linear independence of the $L_i$. This is not the essence of the linear independence argument, though; it is the specific machinery that gets us there.)

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? The author added, "What is the basis for $V$, of which this is the dual? Such a basis $\{p_{1}, p_{2}, p_{3}\}$ for $V$ must satisfy $L_{i}(p_{j})=\delta_{ij}$ or $p_{j}(t_{i})=\delta_{ij}$." Do you agree with this statement? I don't think that's true because $\{1, x, x^{2}\}$ apparently does not satisfy those conditions.

Comment: I do agree with that statement. I also agree that $1 , x, x^2$ doesn't satisfy those conditions and hence is not the dual basis. What you have to do to find the dual basis is to solve for $p_1, p_2, p_3$ in the equations $p_j(t_i) = \delta_{ij}$ given $t_1, t_2, t_3$.

Comment: The author apparently talks about the basis for $V$ not $V^{*}$, and I think your comment is about a basis for $V^{*}$. Am I right?

Comment: No, the bases $\{1,x,x^2\}$ and $\{L_1,L_2,L_3\}$ are *not* dual of each other, in general! But that doesn't matter in the economy of the proof.

Comment: The polynomials $p_j$ will be a basis of $V$. If they satisfy the equations in my comment, they will be what we call the "dual basis [to the basis $L_i$ of $V^*$]"

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical interpolation fact: a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ is completely determined by its values at $n+1$ distinct points.

Which, in itself, is a generalization of the fact that there's only one line through two distinct points.

Comment: I agree $\{1, x, x^{2}\}$ does span $V$. However, my question here is how I can *explicitly* identify the need for choosing a basis as a system of linear equations. The fact that polynomials are not vectors themselves in this example made me astray.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: what you mean *polynomials are not vectors*? The polynomials **are** the vectors in the vector space of polynomials.